# Cannot find module axios - compatibility issue with typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios

I installed Axios local to my Typescript project, but generate an error when trying to import it. Error: "Cannot Find module axios".

root folder

```
npm install --save-dev axios
```

src/app.ts

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

package.json

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
```

It has something to do with my tsconfig.json. If I remove this file, axios is known. If I restore this file, the error comes back in VS Code. I know for Lodash package there is a Lodash types (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash) to make lodash compatible with typescript. Is there an equivelent for axios?

I have this file .\node_modules\axios\index.d.ts that is supposed to help me out with typescript compatibility. Somehow it's not working.

Comment: is it dev depenedncy?

Comment: try this npm install --save axios 
don't install axios with dev dependency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to help. It lets TS understand Axios. Even though Axios was supposed to work out of the box.

```
npm install --save @types/axios
```

Comment: @types/axios is now deprecated. Axios now provides it's own type definitions.

Answer (score 0):

suggestion - use:
`npm install --save axios` instead

`--save-dev` flag is for those packages that are not part of your app and needed for development purposes such as running tests, transpiling, compiling code etc.

However `--save-dev` should have been work:

1. check if `node_modules/axios` folder exists.
2. try `rm -rf node_modules` and run `npm install` again

Comment: I tried that, no change. It has something to do with typescript not recognizing the package. I know this because it works when removing tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in my `http.ts` file.

```
import axios, { Method, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.HOST_BACKEND,
  });
  
  const request = <T>(
    method: Method,
    url: string,
    params: any
  ): Promise<AxiosResponse<T>> => {
    return api.request<T>({
      method,
      url,
      params,
    });
  };
  
  export default request;
```

It happens because of typescript usage. I resolved by reinstalling `axios npm` package using `@types/` like below

```
npm install --save @types/axios
```